# Count values by year in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I need to display total number of job postings in each year. Print the year that had most jobs, and plot a simple line graph to see if jobs rise with each passing year.

How can I pull that data from a csv file?

```
all_data = pd.read_csv('all_data_master.csv') 
all_data = all_data.replace('\\N',np.nan)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this:

```
 all_data ['post_date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data ['post_date'])
 post_by_years = all_data ['post_date'].dt.year.value_counts()

 # max post
 post_by_years.iloc[0]

 # plot:
 post_by_years.plot()
```